# Explanation on angle of inclination

Tags: geometry

I was solving some problems today and came across this question of which (i found the answer to) the answer perplexed me, so the question itself was pretty simple calculate the angle of inclination,α given the gradient (m),and the y intercept.

My working out to the question:

> y=-x-16, where x is the gradient and -16 is the y intercept, the slope is -1, and for inclination it is -1 = tanθ = $\tan^{-1}$(-1) which equals -45 (on my calculator)

BUT

When i checked the answers it said it is α = 135°, how?

Comment: It's basically the same. You'll see if you plot those on $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context:  angle of inclination refers to the angle that an angle rotates from the positive side of the $x$-axis, counterclockwise.  As such, for any angle of inclination $\theta$, we must have $\theta\in[0^\circ,180^\circ]$.

Solving the trigonometric equation $\tan\theta=-1$, we have:

Let $\tan\alpha=1, \alpha\in[0^\circ,90^\circ]\implies\alpha=45^\circ$.
Since $\tan\theta<0$, we have $\theta\in(90^\circ,180^\circ)$.  Therefore, $\theta=180^\circ-\alpha=135^\circ$ as required.